# Maintain user history in JIRA when migrating from internal directory to LDAP

Tags: ldap, jira

We are currently using JIRA's internal directory with 800 users.

We manage these users by hand but we plan to migrate to LDAP. Our company has an LDAP server where these peopleWe are currently using JIRA's internal directory with 800 users.

We managed these users by hand at the beginning but we want to use LDAP. Our company has an LDAP server where these users are already present. The uid (username) is the same.

We have tried to add the LDAP directory in the configuration, on top, before the internal directory. We got that group membership is lost (We think that user's activity ownership maybe too but didn't do the test).

We don't want to lose neither users' history nor their groups.

Is that possible? How?

PD: Maybe anything to do with entryUUID JIRA's config parameter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We found that it's posible to migrate users from the internal directory to LDAP and maintain their activity in particular circunstances, as follow.

The **configuration of authentication** that we used was like this (with this order):

1. Internal directory
2. LDAP server (read-only option or read-only with local groups)

**Condition to meet:** the username must be registered in both directories.

**Procedure:** Just go to the user's management page and delete the user. JIRA will automatically detect that the user is within the other directory too and  reassign the history as if owned by the LDAP user.

**Notes:**

- If the user is now registered in the LDAP, JIRA will see that the user has an history (comments and issues assigned) and it will abort the deletion.
- The data reassigned includes activity (issues, assignments and comments), but do not contain groups. After migrating the user, it is needed to add the user to the groups.

Comment: The activity isn't migrated to LDAP. The user is recognized as the same in both LDAPs. Different thing altogether.